# my Ubuntu 18.04 takes forever to shutdown

Tags: shutdown

[image][image][image: The messages after shutdown]My system takes forever to shutdown. I have tried "shutdown now" have tried killing suspect processes.
Attached is a pic of my screen hanging.

Thx in advance

Comment: Look at the logs:`journalctl -b -1 -e` . For some reason, you're doing an `fsck` on `/dev/nvme0n1p2`. Why?

Comment: You may have a HDD/SSD problem. Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Lets first check your file system for errors. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, open a terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, type `sudo fdisk -l`, identify the `/dev/XXXX` device name for your "Linux Filesystem", then type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX`, replacing `XXXX` with the number you found earlier. Repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors, then reboot and update your question with the results.

Comment: While you're booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start the `Disks` application, and take screenshots of the SMART Data for your HDD/SSD. It might take two screenshots to capture all of the data. Upload them to imgur.com

Comment: Will try doing as you suggested. This is a PC I built myself. I used a NVME M2 SSD, just mounted it on the motherboard and loaded the Ubuntu via a USB. I wonder if I had to "format" or do anything to the SSD!! The SSD is the only memory for the OS to load on, no HDD. With 16GB of RAM FYI

Comment: I have the journalctl file, not sure how to share it here

Comment: Hope the pictures help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the info, but we didn't get it right. Did you do the `fdisk` part? Your `fsck` wasn't run on the correct partition. I suspect the command should have been `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2`. In the `Disks` app, you need to open the "hamburger" menu and select `SMART Data & Tests`. Open the SMART Data window, take a screenshot, scroll the window text if need be, take another screenshot. Edit your question with the proper results.

Comment: Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: Also, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete.

Comment: Hi again. After the last comments, i decided to reload 18.4. The previous problems disappeared only to be replaced with a new one. Againshutdown takes for ever. Please see the last pic

Comment: @heynnema. Hope you can see my last comment. Thx

Comment: Did you re-attempt the `fsck` commands, and run `memtest`?

Comment: @heynnema. Greetings, done the meatiest, see the screen shot. Zero errors. The fsck also looks fine.

Comment: Good job on your fsck and memtest! What make/model is your motherboard? Find the current BIOS version with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Check for a new BIOS at the manufacturer's web site. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema. Thanks for your response. Memtest, sorry for the spell checker. Current Bios version is F5. My motherboard is  Z390 I AORUS PRO WIFI. F5 is a March 2019 version. there is a F6 and F7a.

Comment: I rather not upgrade my Bios, never done that and I would rather avoid if possible, and try other avenues before.

Comment: @Babek Don't be afraid of a BIOS update. Just do a good backup of your important files first, then flash the new BIOS. Done.

Comment: @heynnema. Thx for the response.What is the best Ubuntu backup procedure to use? Never done that before. I have a NAS on the network. Thx

Comment: Can also use an attached external storage

Comment: I personally use 3 methods. I use the `Backups` utility that's included with Ubuntu to backup select folders from my home folder, I use `TimeShift` to backup my system, and I use Windows `Macrium Reflect` to clone my entire disk, all to external disks. If you've only got a small amount of important data, you could also just drag and drop the files to an external disk.

Comment: One last thing to try is to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Use version 19.04 or newer. See if the problem goes away. You can hit the ESC key during shutdown to view the messages, and see where the shutdown hangs/takes so long.

Comment: @heynnema. Thanks for the backup recommendations. I haven't tried them, but I will. However, I did the BIOS update, as you suggested. It seems to have improved things quite a bit. Will get back in a few days, once I am certain of the outcome. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

- we checked the file system of the system disk, `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p2`, it ran fine
- we ran a memory diagnostic, `memtest` from https://www.memtest86.com/, it ran fine
- user reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04
- we checked the BIOS version for motherboard " Z390 I AORUS PRO WIFI", `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and found version F5, and the current version is F7a. User updated the BIOS and the machine seems to be running fine now.

Backup recommendations:

I personally use 3 methods. I use the `Backups` utility that's included with Ubuntu to backup select folders from my home folder, I use `TimeShift` to backup my system, and I use Windows `Macrium Reflect` to clone my entire disk, all to external disks. If you've only got a small amount of important data, you could also just drag and drop the files to an external disk.

Comment: Thanks heynnema. It now shuts down too quickly. But I am not complaining. Going through the process i learnt a lot more things, thanks for your support.